# AWS SDK Go Lambda Unit Testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, aws-lambda

I'm trying to wrap my head around writing some unit tests for the first time ever, and I'm doing it in golang for a side project utilising aws lambda.

Below are two files.

`main.go` takes an event containing an email address, and creates the user in a cognito user pool.

`main_test.go` is supposed to mock the `createUser` function in `main.go`, but I'm getting an error when I try to run the test.

I've just switched my code from [instantiating the client globally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html#golang-handler-state) to using pointer receiver methods on the aws sdk interfaces after watching [this youtube video](http://%20%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv-42EWBsos).

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    cidp "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
    cidpif "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider/cognitoidentityprovideriface"
    lib "github.com/sean/repo/lib"
)

type createUserEvent struct {
    EmailAddress string `json:"email_address"`
}

type awsService struct {
    cidpif.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI
}

func (c *awsService) createUser(e createUserEvent) error {
    input := &cidp.AdminCreateUserInput{
        UserPoolId:             aws.String(os.Getenv("USER_POOL_ID")),
        Username:               aws.String(e.EmailAddress),
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: []*string{aws.String("EMAIL")},
        ForceAliasCreation:     aws.Bool(true),
        UserAttributes: []*cidp.AttributeType{
            {
                Name:  aws.String("email"),
                Value: aws.String(e.EmailAddress),
            },
        },
    }
    _, err := c.AdminCreateUser(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case cidp.ErrCodeResourceNotFoundException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeResourceNotFoundException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeUserNotFoundException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeUserNotFoundException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeUsernameExistsException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeUsernameExistsException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInvalidPasswordException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInvalidPasswordException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeCodeDeliveryFailureException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeCodeDeliveryFailureException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeUnexpectedLambdaException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeUnexpectedLambdaException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeUserLambdaValidationException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeUserLambdaValidationException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInvalidLambdaResponseException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInvalidLambdaResponseException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodePreconditionNotMetException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodePreconditionNotMetException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInvalidSmsRoleAccessPolicyException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInvalidSmsRoleAccessPolicyException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeTooManyRequestsException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeTooManyRequestsException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeNotAuthorizedException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeUnsupportedUserStateException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeUnsupportedUserStateException, aerr.Error())
            case cidp.ErrCodeInternalErrorException:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v, %v", cidp.ErrCodeInternalErrorException, aerr.Error())
            default:
                log.Printf("[ERROR] %v", err.Error())
            }
        } else {
            log.Printf("[ERROR] %v", err.Error())
        }
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("[INFO] Created new user %v successfully", e.EmailAddress)
    return nil
}

func (c *awsService) handler(e createUserEvent) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    headers := map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    err := c.createUser(e)
    if err != nil {
        resp := lib.GenerateResponseBody(fmt.Sprintf("Error creating user %v", e.EmailAddress), 404, err, headers)
        return resp, nil
    }

    resp := lib.GenerateResponseBody(fmt.Sprintf("Created new user %v", e.EmailAddress), 200, nil, headers)
    return resp, nil
}

func main() {
    c := awsService{cidp.New(session.New())}

    lambda.Start(c.handler)
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    cidp "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
    cidpif "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider/cognitoidentityprovideriface"
)

type mockCreateUser struct {
    cidpif.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI
    Response cidp.AdminCreateUserOutput
}

func (d mockCreateUser) CreateUser(e createUserEvent) error {
    return nil
}

func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Successfully create user", func(t *testing.T) {
        m := mockCreateUser{Response: cidp.AdminCreateUserOutput{}}
        c := awsService{m}

        err := os.Setenv("USER_POOL_ID", "ap-southeast-2_ovum4dzAL")
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }

        err = c.createUser(createUserEvent{EmailAddress: "user@example.com"})
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal("User should have been created")
        }
    })
}
```

**the error**

```
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestCreateUser$ github.com/sean/repo/src/create_user

--- FAIL: TestCreateUser (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestCreateUser/Successfully_create_user (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x60 pc=0x137c2f2]

goroutine 6 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.1(0x13e00c0, 0x173fd70)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1072 +0x30d
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc000001b00)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1075 +0x41a
panic(0x13e00c0, 0x173fd70)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
github.com/sean/repo/src/create_user.(*mockCreateUser).AdminCreateUser(0xc00000ee40, 0xc00006a200, 0xc00001e39d, 0x18, 0xc0000b24b0)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x32
github.com/sean/repo/src/create_user.(*awsService).createUser(0xc000030738, 0x145bbca, 0x10, 0x18, 0x0)
    /Users/sean/code/github/sean/repo/src/create_user/main.go:39 +0x2b7
github.com/sean/repo/src/create_user.TestCreateUser.func1(0xc000001b00)
    /Users/sean/code/github/sean/repo/src/create_user/main_test.go:30 +0x10c
testing.tRunner(0xc000001b00, 0x1476718)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0xef
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1168 +0x2b3
FAIL    github.com/sean/repo/src/create_user    0.543s
FAIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is, that you wanted to mock the `AdminCreateUser()` method, but did actually mock the `CreateUser()` method.

Therefore, when you create a new instance of the `mockCreateUser` struct, that "implements" the `cidpif.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI` interface, and then call the `AdminCreateUser()` method on it, it is not implemented and fails.

The relevant code in your `main_test.go` should be this:

```
type mockCreateUser struct {
    cidpif.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI
    Response cidp.AdminCreateUserOutput
}

func (d mockCreateUser) CreateUser(e createUserEvent) error {
    return nil
}
```

It should be enough to add the following "dummy" (and remove the `CreateUser()` method):

```
func (d mockCreateUser) AdminCreateUser(*cidp.AdminCreateUserInput) (*cidp.AdminCreateUserOutput, error) {
    return d.Response, nil
}
```

---

Furthermore, I'd like to propose a slightly different approach to unit testing your Lambdas. You code is already pretty good in terms of testability. But you can do better.

I would propose to create an "application" that acts similar to your `awsService` struct, but does not implement any of the AWS interfaces. Instead, it contains a `configuration` struct. This configuration contains values that you read from the environment (e.g. `USER_POOL_ID`, `EMAIL`) and also instances of the AWS services.

The idea is that all of your methods and functions use this configuration, allowing you to use mock AWS services during unit testing and use "proper" service instances during runtime.

What follows is a simplified version of your Lambda. Obviously, naming etc. is up to you. There is also a lot of error handling missing etc.

The biggest advantage I think is, that you can very easily modify the input to your methods/functions through the `config` of the `application`. If you want to use different email etc. per test and different behaviour, you do that by simply changing the configuration.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider/cognitoidentityprovideriface"
)

type createUserEvent struct {
    EmailAddress string `json:"email_address"`
}

type configuration struct {
    poolId string
    idp    cognitoidentityprovideriface.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI
}

type application struct {
    config configuration
}

func (app *application) createUser(event createUserEvent) error {
    input := &cognitoidentityprovider.AdminCreateUserInput{
        UserPoolId:             aws.String(app.config.poolId),
        Username:               aws.String(event.EmailAddress),
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: aws.StringSlice([]string{"EMAIL"}),
        ForceAliasCreation:     aws.Bool(true),
        UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
            {
                Name:  aws.String("email"),
                Value: aws.String(event.EmailAddress),
            },
        },
    }

    _, err := app.config.idp.AdminCreateUser(input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (app *application) handler(event createUserEvent) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    err := app.createUser(event)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, nil
}

func main() {
    config := configuration{
        poolId: os.Getenv("USER_POOL_ID"),
        idp:    cognitoidentityprovider.New(session.Must(session.NewSession())),
    }

    app := application{config: config}

    lambda.Start(app.handler)
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider/cognitoidentityprovideriface"
)

type mockAdminCreateUser struct {
    cognitoidentityprovideriface.CognitoIdentityProviderAPI
    Response *cognitoidentityprovider.AdminCreateUserOutput
    Error    error
}

func (d mockAdminCreateUser) AdminCreateUser(*cognitoidentityprovider.AdminCreateUserInput) (*cognitoidentityprovider.AdminCreateUserOutput, error) {
    return d.Response, d.Error
}

func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Successfully create user", func(t *testing.T) {
        idpMock := mockAdminCreateUser{
            Response: &cognitoidentityprovider.AdminCreateUserOutput{},
            Error:    nil,
        }

        app := application{config: configuration{
            poolId: "test",
            idp:    idpMock,
        }}

        err := app.createUser(createUserEvent{EmailAddress: "user@example.com"})
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal("User should have been created")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This was massively helpful, thank you! I'm completely converted with regards to an application struct. I initially liked the `init()` way of doing things, but this is clearner. Plus, I have a feeling that `main()` is run just once after the cold boot, and then each subsequent invocation of the lambda will only run `lambda.Start(app.handler)` which accomplishes the same end where you're not instantiating a client each run. Will add some logging to double check :)

Comment: @Sean You are absolutely right. The `application` with the `configuration` and it's service clients is only created once, when the Lambda is initialised. Which is great, because it makes subsequent invocations a tiny bit faster. And as I explained, it makes testing a lot easier. So win-win :)

Comment: Hey @Jens, here's another question for you. How do I go about testing the function in this paste https://pastebin.com/JZcvXXBH? 

I get a panic error as `*resp.UserPoolClient.ClientSecret` is nil in the debugger when running my test, but is also what I'm trying to return in my test here https://pastebin.com/NJgResz4

I'm trying to return the dereferenced pointer == string, rather than the pointer. Perhaps I shouldn't do this?

Comment: @Sean Can you please create a new question for this. Answering questions like this in comments is not really great and hard to find for others.

Comment: 1000%, that makes perfect sense. Here's the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767851/golang-unit-tests-panic-when-returning-dereferenced-struct-attribute-rather-than